# Trouble with function to determine if something is an anagram

Tags: c++, anagram

I was just working on some challenges on codewars.  This particular one is about writing a function to determine is two words are anagrams - meaning they contain the same letters, maybe just out of order.

I am very new to C++ so I am probably overlooking something very basic.  Here is the code I wrote, when I run it, main tests the anagram function with the two strings "orang" and "apple" and the program outputs 1(true) meaning that its saying those two words are anagrams when they are not.  If I try "orange" and "apple", it outputs 0(false) which is correct. Basically, it is just comparing based on the length of the words and not their individual letter counts.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std; 

bool isAnagram(std::string test, std::string original){
  //your code here
  map<char, int> freqTest;
  map<char, int> freqOrig;
  for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
      char c = tolower(test[i]);
      freqTest[c]++;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
      char c = tolower(test[i]);
      freqOrig[c]++;
  }
  
  return freqTest == freqOrig;
}


// Main function 
int main() 
{ 
    string str1 = "orang";
    string str2 = "apple";
    cout<<isAnagram(str1, str2)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You have typo: you might factorize your code by creating a function to create frequency map, `return compute_frequency(test) == compute_frequency(original);` issue might be easier to spot then if you use `test` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple bug:

```
for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
      char c = tolower(test[i]); //  Should be original[i] instead of test[i]
      freqOrig[c]++;
  }
```

Change `tolower(test[i])` to `tolower(original[i])`

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Ricky You would if you had printed the maps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using to much power to address a simple problem. You could use just one map, adding for one string and subtracting for the other then checking if any value in the map is different from 0.

You could also replace to lowercase in the strings, sort them then compare.

```
#include <algorithm>

for(int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++)
    test[i] = tolower(test[i]);
for(int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++)
    original[i] = tolower(original[i]);
sort(test.begin(), test.end());
sort(original.begin(), original.end());
return test == original;
```

Comment: "Use a different algorithm" is a little bit outside the scope of this question, imo, especially since it's entirely possible to fix the implementation of the asker's approach.

Comment: I cannot see why this would be so much faster. The time complexity is the same.

Comment: @klutt: During subtraction you have the possibility of early exit if any entry becomes negative.  And if you do that, you don't even have to walk the map at the end checking for non-zero, because with two inputs of equal length it is a zero-sum game, if any entry ends up positive then there must be at least one corresponding negative entry that caused early exit.  Of course I assume that you start by comparing the lengths for a really easy early exit.

Comment: @NathanPierson I said he could do with just one map, same algorithm. Then I suggested a simpler way to achieve what he wanted

Comment: @klutt the time complexity is basically the same, I know. What about space and size/simplicity of code?

Comment: @vmp TBH, I don't think your code makes it any simpler. They are pretty much the same. Actually, I think OP:s code is a bit clearer. The space complexity is also the same, even though your version saves a very tiny bit of memory, but unless this algorithm is called simultaneously by millions of threads (it won't) the memory saved is completely irrelevant.  If saving memory actually is an issue, you should use references or pointers instead. But if you do, then your code will also modify the arguments which might be unwanted.

Comment: @vmp Hmmm, I only looked at your code and not what you wrote first. Well, using just one map like that does make sense, but to me it smells like premature optimization.

Comment: @klutt that is my point. He already passed the argument by value... There is no need to make 2 more copies (the maps).... If he had passed by reference and used map then the performance would probably be equivalent to pass by value and sort.

Comment: @vmp Well, nevertheless. If OP:s code was overcomplicated it would be a good thing to give advice about that, but I think performance and memory optimization is a bit overkill in this case. :)